# Is is possible to show a custom right-click menu in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, right-click

Just wondering if it is possible to show a movie clip based menu inside a Flash movie when the user "right-clicks" an item (a button or movie clip for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a great place to start:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html

Comment: Seems like I can add items to the menu depending on which movie-clip was right-clicked.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can add items to the menu, but not completely replace it with a custom system.

Comment: Any example of how to add a custom item in the menu?